# Node Express dynamic route/path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

How can I implement and get a dynamic route or path with Express package? The main problem is the path is an id pass by the client and had no control over it.

```
const express = require('express');
const dynamic_path= express();


dynamic_path.get('/user', (req, res) => {

});

exports.v1 = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(dynamic_path);
```

The above will result as `https://my-app.net/v1/user` and the client request will be `https://my-app.net/v1/user/user_id`. I need to allow dynamic path and I need to get the value of `user_id` as well for future usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added `:user_id` to the route.

```
dynamic_path.get('/user/:user_id', (req, res) => {
  const user_id = req.params.user_id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the route:

```
https://my-app.net/v1/user/:user_id
```

Your code will be like this:

```
dynamic_path.get("/user/:user_id" , (req, res)=>{
    let user_id = req.parmas.user_id
}
```